# Windows 7 hibernation behavior

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

Everytime I hibernate my PC via

```
sysinternals psshutdown
shutdown /h
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll, SetSuspendState
```

it kind behaves weird:

1. takes long to hibernate (30s+) (not too many applications running)
2. on wake up it shows the BIOS bootup logo and all the cold boot stuff (as if I had shut down, not hibernated)
3. instead of login screen it shows the windows loading animation, and seems to be loading the OS again

Then when I log in it restores the environment but most programs will crash.

- Main board: Asus P5KSE EPU
- OS Windows 7 64 ultimate
- RAM 4Gb Corsair

Comment: I wonder if psshutdown is compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds normal to me, except for the programs crashing. Hibernation is just about the same as shutdown, except the contents of memory is written to the hibernation file first. If you have many gigabytes of memory, that could easily take 30 seconds or more.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernation process is weird. Most folks just click Start > Shut Down [arrow] > Hibernate.

That said most hibernation problems stem from the BIOS being improperly configured to support the necessary hibernation modes. Go into your BIOS and check to see if you have Sleep / Hibernate setting at S3 or S5.

Edit: This behavior is also exhibited when you hibernate and then cut the power entirely to the system (i.e. as if the system were on a surge protector as many are, and when you hibernate you also flip the power switch on the surge protector). When hibernating you need to keep the system powered.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541

Comment: @Moab yes there is the fact that PSShutdown is 6 years old... ;-)